# Apache2 выводит php код в браузере, а не выполняет

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, php7

Взял самый дешевый vps для своих нужд. ОС - Ubuntu 16.04.1
По инструкции установил apache2 и php7

```
apt-get -y install apache2
apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
systemctl restart apache2
```

Создал тестовый php файлик `<? phpinfo(); ?>` , пытаюсь открыть в браузере - выводится сам php-код.

Много гуглил, но пока безрезультатно. Подскажите пожалуйста, если кто-то сталкивался с подобным.

З.Ы.

- Права файла менял - не стояло "выполнение".
- Включил опцию `short_open_tag` в `php.ini` и перезапустил апач.
- В папке `/etc/apache2/mods-available` есть файлы `php7.0.conf` и
  `php7.0.load`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> В папке /etc/apache2/mods-available есть файлы php7.0.conf и php7.0.load

«available» — это «доступные». рядом есть каталог `mods-enabled`, т.е., «включенные».

вам надо включить модуль `php7.0`. проще всего это сделать командой:

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

---

возможно, модуль называется чуть по-другому. если у вас не отключено авто-дополнение в оболочке, то наберите команду вплоть до слова `php` и нажмите <kbd>tab</kbd> дважды, чтобы узнать точное название.

---

*apache* после этого надо перезапустить.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока удалось запустить nginx, позже попробую сделать так, как вы написали.