# Apache не запускает интерпретатор PHP

Tags: php, apache

Перешел недавно с виртуального хостинга на VPS сервер на debian 7. На виртуальном хостинге мой сайт работал замечательно больше месяца "из коробки". Ничего лишнего настраивать не пришлось. Но на VPS...

Понаслышке знал о том, насколько debian "юзер-френдли". Меня все предупреждали, что надо брать Ubuntu или CentOS, но я, все же решил поставить debian. К тому же это было необходимо для установки трейд-бота.

Купил хостинг, все настроил, подключился по SFTP, загрузил файлы сайта, зашел на сайт, и... В ответ на запрос, сервер выдал в текстовом формате исходный код страницы, включая PHP, без какого-либо форматирования. Просто текст.

Решил проверить, поставлен ли php в принципе?

```
root@cs-bets:/# php5 -v
-bash: php5: command not found
```

С этого момента я стал подозревать, что меня ждет.

Ну, - подумал я - Не такая это и большая проблема.

```
root@cs-bets:/# apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
(...)
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 350 not upgraded.
root@cs-bets:/# apachectl restart
```

После этого, обновив страницу, и увидев интерфейс сайта, я почти успел обрадоваться, пока не заметил PHP - теги на странице, из чего пришел к выводу, что PHP как не интерпретировался, так и не интерпретируется.
Собственно, дальше этого ничего не движется уже второй день. Я что только не делал. И Апач вместе с PHP переустанавливал, и в .htaccess добавлял addHandler, и даже не помню, что ещё.

Во избежание некоторых вопросов заранее отвечу:

Да, в php.ini short_open_tags стоит On
Да, в php.ini engine стоит On
Да, я a2enmod php5 прописывал. Да, он говорит, что это модуль уже установлен
Да, error.log Апача проверял. Единственное, что там было - это предупреждения PHP.   Но их, на всякий случай, тоже исправил. Не помогло.

```
[Sat Dec 10 06:44:35.813718 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5131] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured — resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 10 06:44:35.813749 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5131] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Dec 10 06:47:04.305111 2016] [:error] [pid 5490] [client 95.213.177.123:45119] script '/var/www/html/azenv.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: https://proxyradar.com/
[Sat Dec 10 07:50:39.805186 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5131] AH00173: SIGHUP received. Attempting to restart
[Sat Dec 10 07:50:39.837360 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5131] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured — resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 10 07:50:39.837396 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5131] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Заранее спасибо всем за ответы!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/598185/178576

Comment: Читал, не помогло.

Comment: `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` ?

Comment: И это не `php5 -v` a `php -v` ;)

Comment: @E_p, Апач перезагружал тысячу раз, сервер перезагружал чуть меньше тысячи раз. php5 -v выводит то же самое, что php -v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой debian 8

Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь!