# Не могу зайти в PhpMyAdmin. Слетели настройки Apache 2, не отображает php код

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, apache2

После обновления Ubuntu 16.04, не работает ни один php файл. Слетели настройки apache. Стартовая страница Apache по адресу 127.0.0.1 работает, а мои php файлы - нет

Comment: проверьте работает ли php в целом. ошибку публикуйте в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman изменил. php работает. через консоль в мускл зайти могу, но вот попасть на страницу в phpmyadmin не могу

Comment: как вы проверили php?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman php -v показывает версию) + мой php код, который я писал - работает) Если как-то не так поверил, то подскажите, сейчас все прверю) P.S. не судите строго, я новичек)

Comment: `php -v` - вы проверили консольный php. А нужен php apache (или какой у вас сервер).

Comment: @Crantisz походу ты прав, когда пишу phpinfo();

Comment: то выдает чистую страницу, и никаких изменений хосты были настроены раньше и все работало, а что теперь делать? помоги пожалуйста)

Comment: [`$ sudo a2enmod php...`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598203/178576)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, PHP код в вашем индексном файле воспринимается как текст.
Такое может быть, когда блоки PHP кода начинаются с `<?` вместо `<?php` и параметр short_open_tag отключен.
Проверьте, чтобы в вашем файле php.ini было указано `short_open_tag = On`.
После изменения php.ini сервер необходимо перезапустить.

Comment: поменял значение на On, но ошибка так и осталась. P.S. до этого работало все нормально.